# unable to get parameters in php after rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem when I try to get a parameter from the url after rewriting a rule

This is my url:

> www.mysite.com/pages/example/two/

and this one is supposed to load my rewrite rule

> www.mysite.com/pages/page.php?user=two

The following is my rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^example/(.+)/?$ page.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

I have a second rule for two parameters

```
RewriteRule ^example/(.+)/(.+)$ page.php?user=$1&lang=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I have a `var_dump ($_GET['user']);` in my php, but I get result as a **NULL** and PHP Notice: Undefined index: user in /path/page.php on line 4.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both rules using the generic `.+` placeholder would make this ambiguous. Enable and check the RewriteLog.

Comment: im getting PHP Notice:  Undefined index: user in /path/page.php on line 4.

Comment: let me see if I can activate rewriteLog, I'm using cpanel

Comment: solved, the server was loading an old rule, just add Options-Multiviews to my .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^example/(.*)/?$ page.php?user=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)/(.*)$ page.php?user=$1&lang=$2 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: tried it, but i get null in var_dump ($_GET['user'])

Comment: solved, the server was loading an old rule, just add Options-Multiviews to my .htaccess